# Get system command output in C program

Tags: c, unix, io, operating-system

Is there a better way to do it?

```
int numOfCPU;
system("grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo >> /tmp/cpuinfo");
FILE *fp = fopen("/tmp/cpuinfo", "r");
fscanf(fp, "%d", &numOfCPU);
fclose(fp);
system("rm /tmp/cpuinfo");
```

I don't want to create an intermediary file and then remove it.

EDIT:

Its not about reading from the file. The command can be "ls" or "echo 'Hello world'"

Comment: This is C code. Was about to say C++ but then I noticed FILE*.

Comment: I replaced java tag to c because the code is in c.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Ok, I was confused in my other answer. In any case, the philosophy in this answer is the same. You can use directly the **popen** function.

Then you have something like this:

```
int numOfCPU;
FILE *fp = popen("grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo", "r");

fscanf(fp, "%d", &numOfCPU);
pclose(fp);
```

I hope it will be useful.

Comment: for example that command prompts the output after few seconds continuously then how to program monitor ouput?

Answer (score 4):

You need to use redirection and pipes to do what you are trying to do.

The *popen* call can help you, but if you want something more flexible, such as also redirecting input, or more secure, such as not running a string in the shell, you should follow this example, taking from the manual page of pipe.

```
   #include <sys/wait.h>
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <unistd.h>
   #include <string.h>

   int
   main(int argc, char *argv[])
   {
       int pipefd[2];
       pid_t cpid;
       char buf;

       if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <string>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }
       if (pipe(pipefd) == -1) {
           perror("pipe");
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }

       cpid = fork();
       if (cpid == -1) {
           perror("fork");
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }

       if (cpid == 0) {    /* Child reads from pipe */
           close(pipefd[1]);          /* Close unused write end */

           while (read(pipefd[0], &buf, 1) > 0)
               write(STDOUT_FILENO, &buf, 1);

           write(STDOUT_FILENO, "\n", 1);
           close(pipefd[0]);
           _exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

       } else {            /* Parent writes argv[1] to pipe */
           close(pipefd[0]);          /* Close unused read end */
           write(pipefd[1], argv[1], strlen(argv[1]));
           close(pipefd[1]);          /* Reader will see EOF */
           wait(NULL);                /* Wait for child */
           exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
       }
    }
```

You should modify the child process to use dup2 to redirect the standard output to the pipe and then exec the command you want it to run.

Answer (score -2):

**Using awk**:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int numOfCPU =0;

    system ("awk '/processor/{numOfCPU++}END{print numOfCPU}' /proc/cpuinfo");
}
```